# C# Unknown Text Found

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I'm creating a program to transfer text from a word document to a database. During some testing I came across some text inside a textbox after setting it's text to a table cell range as follows:

```
textBox1.Text = oDoc.Tables[1].Cell(1, 3).Range.Text;
```

What appeared in the form was:

[image]

What wasn't expected was the dot at the end of the text and I have no idea what it is supposed to represent. The dot can be highlighted but if you try and copy and paste it nothing appears. You can delete the dot manually. Can anyone help me identify what this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identification bit shouldn't be too hard:

```
string text = oDoc.Tables[1].Cell(1, 3).Range.Text;
textBox1.Text = ((int) text[4]).ToString("x4");
```

That will give you the Unicode UTF-16 code unit for that character... you can then find out what it is on the [Unicode web site](http://unicode.org). (I usually look at the [Charts](http://unicode.org/charts) page or the [directory of PDFs](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/) and guess which chart it will be in based on the numbering - it's not ideal, and there are probably better ways, but it's always worked well enough for me...)

Of course when you've identified it you'll still need to work out what the heck it's doing there... does the original Word document just have "HOLD"?

Comment: thank you, got the code 000d which turned out to be a carriage return.